# Переадресация пользователя на страницу с массивом $_POST laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post

Например есть форма:

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="post" action="https://site.com/" enctype="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
```

Как сделать средствами laravel переадрессацию на линк с $_POST массивом.
Например пользователь нажимает на ссылку и через котроллер собирается массив и передается методом post + пользователь попадает на ссылку, как будто заполнил форму и отправил.

Comment: а в чем конкретно проблема?

Answer (score 0):

впервые без етого на laravel не сработает post request

```
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value=" {{csrf_token()}} ">
```

ето только для зашиты  сайта а во вторых  надо на web.php писать route на ссылку и путь к контроллеру а потом все логика пишутся на контроллере